"Reached the maximum number of URI tags for http.client.requests" how do i deal with this warning?
I've tried everthing mentioned here, but can't seem to find what the issue is
There is no place in my code where i build an uri, except from tests.
Any idea whats causing the issue?
Ive tried everything, nowhere in my code i concatanate uris or even build them.
